# How did Conan enter primary school without any official papers?

Tags: detective-conan

I watched DC and I always had a question: how did Conan enter primary school without any official papers or birth certificate?

Did they ever try to justify this part? For example faking documents, or enrolling exceptionally in an unofficial way.

Comment: Why would one need official papers to be admitted to a school? Seems like unnecessary overhead. Also, what kind of official papers would someone that age have, other then the birth certificate? Which is something that could reasonably be in the hands of his parents, who were explained to be overseas.

Comment: "Why would one need official papers to be admitted to a school?" whaaaat!? any school in the countries where I lived/live, would ask for parents ID + child birth certificate, without these documents you just can't get into school. isn't that the case in Japan?

Comment: And if the kid were to be sent to school by someone else other than his parents, this someone else needs to present official papers of custody by the parents of the child.

Comment: Is education compulsory in your country? In mine, whether parents want to or not, kids have to go to school. Therefore missing documentation wouldn't be a valid reason to prevent school entry.

Comment: No, it's not, but it will still require papers, dunno if missing papers will prevent entry, but they will still ask for it. Even if they don't have the birth certificate the school will simply try to obtain a copy from local authorities by matching prefecture, father name, and mother name.

Comment: I am just 100% sure you can't just walk into school and enroll with " konichiwa my name is XXX YYY" So my question is perhaps did they ever try to justify this fact in conan anime/manga? or is it just one of those simplifications that we will pretend it never existed just to keep the anime running for 2k episodes? after all, the entire anime is based on an illogical shrinking drug, and I kid who encounter a murderer twice per day so it won't really shock me if their parallel universe has no papers. It's just plain absurd how he is always stressed about passport, but not birth certificate...

Comment: They never even bothered to explain how smartphones were a thing in 1996. Or how Conan can celebrate twenty new years without aging. But yeah, I find nothing strange about Conan and Haibara enrolling without having any documentation, other then their current place of residence. If they were born overseas no one would bother checking anyway.

Comment: "They never even bothered to explain how smartphones were a thing in 1996." hahah true the smartphone thing also bothered me, they just appeared all of a sudden, but for that you could just pretend that the anime adapts, as if the story just started in 2020, but passport problem to travel will always be a problem no matter in what era the anime starts

Comment: Conan does get papers down the line to travel around. As birth certificates can literally go up in smokes, it's also not surprising for there to be methods to enter the system after all your documentation is gone. Unlike it used to the case back in the days. There's a movie about this called "The Captain from Köpenick" about someone forced into crime, since he can't get work without papers, but to get papers he needs to have proof that he works in the country.

Comment: I think Haibara also enrolled the same way like Conan, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

All we know is that in Chapter 10, Professor Agasa "processed all the forms", probably claiming that Conan is his relative as he told Ran in Chapter 2.

Being a genius for science and engineering, he may have forged Conan's birth certificate.